# Querying users in Firebase with unique UID's as keys using Swift

Tags: database, swift, firebase

I'm trying to query users by lowercaseString name which I auto save when a user signs up.  The thing is I'm creating keys for users using their uid's.  Now I'm having trouble letting other users find their friends because all I'm pulling back is the very first key "user". Here's my firebase info...
[image: Firebase data of user with keys: caseUsername, displayName, follows, and image]

Here is my code...

```
let userRef = self.ref.childByAppendingPath("users")
userRef.queryOrderedByChild("caseUsername")
       .queryStartingAtValue(self.searchTXTFLD.text?.lowercaseString, childKey: "caseUsername")
       .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
           print(snapshot.key)
```

Please help me find users using `self.searchTXTFLD.text?.lowercaseString`. It should equal user child `caseUsername`.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Frank van Puffelen.  The answer illuminated more about how Firebase data should be structured.  I didn't completely use your answer, but here is what I have and what works.

```
  @IBAction func searchFriendsACTN(sender: AnyObject)
        {
            let queryRef = self.ref.childByAppendingPath("users")
            queryRef.queryOrderedByChild("caseUsername")
                .queryEqualToValue(self.searchTXTFLD.text?.lowercaseString)
                .queryLimitedToFirst(1)
                .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
                    if snapshot.exists()
                    {
                        var newIds = [String]()
                        var newNames = [String]()
                        var newCsnames = [String]()
                        var newPics = [String]()
                        for items in snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
                        {
                            let ids = items.key
                            let names = items.value["displayName"] as! String
                            let csnames = items.value["caseUsername"] as! String
                            let pics = items.value["image"] as! NSString

                            newIds.append(ids as! String)
                            newNames.append(names)
                            newCsnames.append(csnames)
                            newPics.append(pics as String)
                        }
                        self.caseUserNameArray = newCsnames
                        self.usersID = newIds
                        self.usernameArray = newNames
                        self.photos = newPics
                        self.friendsTBLVW.reloadData()
                    }
                })
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a query, there may be multiple children that match the condition. When you then listen for the `.Value` event, Firebase will return a snapshot that contains a list of the matching children. Even if there is only one matching child, it will still be in a list.

So the solution is to iterate over the matching children:

```
ref.queryOrderedByChild("caseUsername")
   .queryStartingAtValue(self.searchTXTFLD.text?.lowercaseString, childKey: "caseUsername")
   .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
       for child in snapshot.children {
           print(child.key);
       }
   });
```